# How to organize code for multiple Go projects?

Tags: go

So, I have a few web services written in Go and I am planning to write a few more. The services all live in their own folders outside of GOPATH and use Glide and Dep for managing vendored dependencies (I intend to convert to Go 1.11 modules in the near future).

The problem I am having is that there is a lot of code duplication in these services, making things fragile. Especially code related to database structure and access. I would like to move all the database access and other service specific code into a shared location somewhere and import it into the services as needed.

What is the right way to do that? I have been experimenting with different project structures, but I always run into one of the two problems.

If I use Go 1.11 modules, I end up having to share go.mod and go.sum between all the services. This makes the build process for individual services longer, since each service build has to fetch all of the dependencies from all the services in the same location. As my number of services will grow, this problem will become worse.

If I set GOPATH so my service code ends up inside, I run into multiple problems. The services are part of a larger project written in a different language and are part of the version control repository for the project. The structure, currently, is

```
- project
    - services
        - svc1
        - svc2
    - othercode
    - morecode
```

If I set the GOPATH to services, I have to move individual services directories under a separate src, I end up with extra pkg and bin directories and every Go package I ever want to install ends up somewhere in the ~/project/services tree as well. I would rather keep using vendored dependencies.

How do I organize my code, so I avoid either of the above scenarios and still be able to import shared code from multiple services?

Comment: First issue, you should never be setting GOROOT

Comment: GOROOT, GOPATH, whatever. I don't want every go package I install to end up in my project repo :)

Comment: Besides, I am not sure what you mean. How else would I set the default location for all the Go stuff?

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). (hint: there's no mention of GOROOT)

Comment: OK, they are using GOPATH, I believe the end result is the same whichever one of these you set.

Comment: That text does not help me with my problem though.

Comment: I have read up a bit, and changed GOROOT references to GOPATH. Looks like GOROOT is about where Go is installed and GOPATH is where the code is supposed to live.

Comment: So what is your problem? Is it that your build is too slow? How slow? How many lines of code are you trying to compile? Are you compiling 20MLOC in two minutes or 2KLOC in two minutes? What do you mean by fetching dependencies? Are you doing `go get` for each dep on each build? If so, you should vendor your deps and not do fetching each time.

Comment: I have written all of this in the question. I do not want to use GOPATH because it polutes my folder structure. And I do not want to share dependencies between all of my services. I build using Docker multi-stage containers. Every time one of the dependecies changes every service build needs to refetch all of the dependencies for all the services. Besides, I expect that eventually I will run into a situation where some of my services require different versions of the same library and with my current setup I cannot do that.

Comment: If you follow the linked article GOPATH won't pollute anything besides the folder it points to, which should not be your project folder.

Comment: I am confused. The article your linked specifically says that all my code should reside inside GOPATH. Specifically in ${GOPATH}/src/path/to/project.

Comment: What I meant is that it doesn't pollute the structure inside ..path/to/project, ie. inside *your project* you do you. But if your complaint is about the src pkg bin inside GOPATH then I can't help you.

Comment: I'm also confused, in your question you point out that you set GOPATH to your services folder, which would pollute your project, but, which is not the same as what the linked article recommends ie ${GOPATH}/src/path/to/project.

Comment: The project is written in a different language and the go services I am trying to work with are just one piece of it. I don't want to move the whole thing under GOPATH for no reason.

Comment: Don't do it for no reason, do it for using the Go language, which is at least 1 reason.

Comment: Besides, having the whole project under ${GOPATH}/src means that all the dependencies are going to end up outside of it and all the built binaries are going to end up outside of it.

Comment: I am not going to have the build environment dictate where I should keep my files. If there is no other option, I might consider switching the language. But I was under impression that vendoring and Go modules in 1.11 were supposed to fix these issues.

Comment: I haven't switched to 1.11 yet so I don't know, sorry for not being of any help.

Comment: So my previous company tried to solve this using Makefiles, it tricked go into thinking that the $GOPATH is actually where the project was and bundled the dependencies inside of the project using godep back then. The downside was using normal go commands was an issue, and you had to build and run always instead of `go run app.go` but it did help with them keeping whatever folder structure they needed and dep also got fooled since makefile provided its own env variables. You can give that a try. I somehow just prefer using vendor though myself.

Comment: Also we did this with go1.4 and 1.6, so this was long back, not sure if it would work now. You can give it a shot on a small test repo though, you probably have a makefile in place anyway to build and make those dockers already I suppose, add some more recipes to it. :)

Comment: I have tried using vendored deps. The problem is that if there is a dependency X and both my shared code and my service code depend on it, Go interprets it as two separate things and gets confused about types throwing "type shared/X is not type svc1/X" errors

Comment: I have been looking into using makefiles or just build scripts. The problem I keep running into is the same. Either I have to share dependency list between all my sub-projects or I end up with a bunch of crap in my repository or if I put the whole project inside GOPATH, I end up with my binaries being built outside of the project tree.

Comment: If there was a way to override the standard src, pkg, bin structure, I might be a happier wombat